# Applying style sheet to android native calendar

Tags: android, iphone, calendar

For my application I need to apply style sheet to Android and Iphone native calendar daily and weekly view. Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No. The Android Calendar is a native app so there is no way to change it's styling.